# Special formatting in SPSS (subscript, superscript)

Tags: formatting, spss

Is it possible in SPSS to insert superscript or subscript characters in labels, specifically axis labels? 
For example, V<sup>2</sup>/Hz. LaTeX commands don't work at all ($\mu V^2$) and there doesn't appear to be any appropriate fields in the property editor.

Does SPSS have the capability? I'm using Version 20 if that is relevant.

Comment: No I do not believe it has that property.

Answer (score 0):

Variable and value labels are plain text.  It is possible to use html or rtf text in places in the Viewer or via the TEXT extension command.

Comment: Would you please be able to provide me with a sample TEXT command? I understand that TEXT comes from the IBM SPSS Statistics - Integration Plug-in for Python, but documentation of SPSS commands are nigh-on non-existent.

Comment: Extension commands have a dialog box interface usually with a Help button to get you started (Utilities > Create Text Output in this case), and for syntax you can do TEXT /HELP or in V23, press F1 on an instance in the Syntax Editor.  TEXT, as it happens, does not have a Help button, but the syntax help, which includes an example of html markup, should get you going.  (If the version you have installed doesn't respond to /HELP or F1, download a newer version via Utilities or from the website.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to get superscript or subscript in SPSS is to use Unicode characters. You can find them on this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts). All numbers are there, but some letters are missing.

I prefer using Unicode subscript/superscript in regular text. The characters will not change if you loose text formatting, though you have limited number of fonts that work.